# Debugging in Eclipse. Moving between breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I'm debugging the JAVA code in Eclipse. Let's say there are 2 breakpoints inside the iterative loop. How to go directly to the breakpoints, while skipping the rest of the code at each iteration?

Comment: Added it as an answer and attached a picture.

Comment: Also note that Ctrl-R works well in places without breakpoints.

Comment: Why this thread has been downvoted without posting any explanation? It looks like some "voters" don´t really read threads, and vote based on their mood. Not a good practice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `resume` button on the debug bar in your IDE. Please see picture attached

[image: resume button]

Answer (score 21):

Press F8 (which is also `Resume` button),that will take you to the break point. From there debug each line with F6.

If you want to go to next break point press F8.

Comment: I was looking for that **F8**

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>F8</kbd> used for Next Debug BreakPoint.

<kbd>F6</kbd> for going line by line after breakpoint.

<kbd>F7</kbd> steps out of currently executed method.