# eclipse step over jumps to next breakpoint

Tags: eclipse

I use Ubuntu 18.4.4 and GCC 7.5 and i downloaded eclipse installer and installed 2020.3. CDT for c++
now when i try to debug the code using step over.it works fine in main function going line by line but when it gets into called function ,step over just jumps to next break point as if it is resume.
i am new to eclipse and I do not know what is the wrong?? 
i found some questions with same behavior for java.
is this the same problem but with C++??
this is another question with similar content without solution [Debugging in Eclipse. Moving between breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960571/debugging-in-eclipse-moving-between-breakpoints)